# Stored Procedure Check if Parameter is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am new to stored procedures, so I really need some help here. I am trying to modify a sp to show all records if the parameter is null, and if it is not null, there is another query for it to run. What I have is getting the error `Procedure of function expects parameter @marketid which was not supplied`. Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

```
ALTER  procedure [dbo].[sp_GetProductDetailsForMarket]
@marketid int

as

IF @marketid IS NOT NULL
begin
SELECT 
p.ProductID, p.pagenumber,p.ProductName,p.Description,p.CategoryID,
   p.ItemNumber,p.Price,p.AlertFrequency,p.PrimaryImageName,
   p.DeletionStateCode,p.Published,p.SearchTerms,p.ThumbNailPath,
   p.UOMName,p.HCPCCode,
   m.marketname,mm.MarketID,
   pa.AttributeID,pa.AttributeValueID,pa.Price as AttributePrice,
   pa.ImagePath,pa.ProductAttributeAssociationID,pa.IsOptional,
   av.[Name] as AttributeValueName,a.[Name] as AttributeName

FROM vPanel_Product p 
INNER JOIN vPanel_MarketMappings mm
        on p.productid=mm.productid
LEFT JOIN vPanel_Market m
        on m.marketid=mm.marketid
LEFT JOIN vPanel_ProductAttributeAssociation pa
       on p.productid = pa.productid
        and pa.deletionstatecode=0
LEFT JOIN vPanel_Attributes a
        on a.AttributeID = pa.AttributeID
        and a.deletionstatecode=0
LEFT JOIN vPanel_AttributeValues av
        on av.attributeValueID = pa.attributeValueID
        and av.deletionstatecode=0
WHERE m.marketid = @marketid
order by p.productname,A.ATTRIBUTEID,AV.ATTRIBUTEVALUEID
end

ELSE 

begin
SELECT 
p.ProductID, p.pagenumber,p.ProductName,p.Description,p.CategoryID,
   p.ItemNumber,p.Price,p.AlertFrequency,p.PrimaryImageName,
   p.DeletionStateCode,p.Published,p.SearchTerms,p.ThumbNailPath,
   p.UOMName,p.HCPCCode,
   pa.AttributeID,pa.AttributeValueID,pa.Price as AttributePrice,
   pa.ImagePath,pa.ProductAttributeAssociationID,pa.IsOptional,
   av.[Name] as AttributeValueName,a.[Name] as AttributeName

FROM vPanel_Product p 
LEFT JOIN vPanel_ProductAttributeAssociation pa
       on p.productid = pa.productid
        and pa.deletionstatecode=0
LEFT JOIN vPanel_Attributes a
        on a.AttributeID = pa.AttributeID
        and a.deletionstatecode=0
LEFT JOIN vPanel_AttributeValues av
        on av.attributeValueID = pa.attributeValueID
        and av.deletionstatecode=0
WHERE @marketid IS NULL
ORDER BY p.productname,A.ATTRIBUTEID,AV.ATTRIBUTEVALUEID
end
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Ok, I will remember that in the future. This database was developed way back in 2008, before my time. I was just modifying it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not in your stored procedure.  Your problem is that your calling application isn't passing the parameter in.  You could default it to null if you want, like this:

```
ALTER  procedure [dbo].[sp_GetProductDetailsForMarket]
@marketid int = NULL
```

Or, you could just always pass it in, null or not.

Comment: Thanks so much @Bill! I can't accept an answer yet because my question is too new, so I just gave you both a point for now. :) Can I accept both as answer?

Comment: @jlg:- NO you cant accept 2 answers. You can accept the one which helped you. Happy coding! :)

Comment: Both answers helped. I guess it just boils down to who answered first. If I choose both as an answer, I would! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Well if it were me, I'd give it to the guy with 4000K reputation.  He'd appreciate it more than the guy with 26,400 reputation.  ;)

Comment: That's a very good point. I was contemplating that myself...but don't worry, this site is ancient and I don't understand a lot of it. I'll have more questions soon I'm sure.

Answer (score 3):

Add the default value to your input paramtere ie **NULL**

```
ALTER  procedure [dbo].[sp_GetProductDetailsForMarket]
@marketid int = NULL
```

So when you will call your stored procedure like this:

```
exec sp_GetProductDetailsForMarket
```

it will not show an error as not the default value of your input parameter **@marketid**  is now set to **NULL**

Comment: amazing! It shows all 3364 rows, just like I need! Hopefully it works in the application too. :)

Comment: @jlg:- It surely will work in your apllication too. Your stored procedure is OK!

Comment: Thanks! That makes me feel less nervous about what I'm doing. :)

Comment: @jlg:- I am sure that will work for you. Dont be nervous. Enjoy your coding.

Comment: Well my code didn't work. I assume it's because marketid is an int and int's will never be `NULL`. I had to change the line `@marketid int = NULL` to `@marketid int = 0`